# Using 12-3 to wire lights/fan, sharing neutral

Tags: bathroom, fans, light

I feel like I am being super paranoid here but I want to make sure I am going to wire these lights correctly... I am going to have two recessed lights and a fan/light combo. The plan is to run 12-3 NM-B in the following manner:

Light is black wire. Fan is red wire.

Stop 1:
First recessed light. 3 blacks wire nutted, 3 whites wirenutted, 2 reds wirenutted. 12-3 romex continues on.

Stop 2:
Fan/light combo.  3 blacks wirenutted. 3 reds wirenutted, 3 neutrals wirenutted (fan/light combo only has 1 neutral wire). 12-3 romex continues on.

Last stop: recessed light. 2 blacks wirenutted, 2 whites wire nutted, red fan circuit is capped off and connected to nothing.

This is an uncommon lighting setup as I would like the fan light to turn on with the rest of the main lights and the fan to be on it's own switch. Of course I would only be switching the hots (black/red) and never the neutral but for some reason I am weary that the fan being on without the lights being on may induce current into the powered-off black through the shared neutral enough to light up the LEDs. I feel like it would only be phantom voltage on a digital multimeter if anything but I don't want to make a mistake like the previous owner who switched the neutral and when I touched the old metal fan/light combo to remove the bulbs the LED and CFL lit up as if I had turned on the switch :| Luckily I did not get shocked... Please let me know if I have a valid concern or if I am just overthinking. Thanks :)

Comment: What are you choosing 12/3?  Are you connecting to an existing circuit that is 20 amp?  I ask this because a 15 amp circuit is adequate and 14 gauge wire is MUCH easier to work with than 12 gauge.  If you just picked 12guage because "heavier wire has gotta be better"  Also you may pick up stray voltage that will make poorly made LED bulbs barely glow, a different brand of bulbs is the answer.

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about induced current. Whatever current is flowing on the red wire, is flowing the other way on the white as well. The magnetic fields that are generated will cancel out, and should prevent any induced currents on the black.

Comment: If you haven't pulled the cables yet, I'd only run 12/2 between the light/fan and the last light. No point in having the extra conductor, unless you're planning to extend the circuit in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, Tyson I am indeed running a 20A circuit for the entire bathroom. Good advice on buying a better brand LED. That makes sense. Tester101 Thanks for trying to save me wire :) but I was keeping the extra red between the fan and last light just incase the fan was inadequate and I needed to GFCI the circuit and move it into the shower but now that I think about it I can do that later in the attic and use 12-2 :) 12-3 is like 3x the cost of 12-2. Your explanation of the red "cancelling" the neutral lead me to further research on EMF to squelch my worries. Thanks :)

Comment: Hint: run 12 gauge wires to receptacles, use a different 15 amp circuit for lighting.  There is a huge difference between working with 12 and 14 gauge wire.

Comment: Tyson it is a 20A circuit. I am trying not to violate code  :P and have no more slots in box (sorry I didn't specify that)

Comment: Though I could just split off another general use circuit... hmmm